# Using a variable in a path

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, path, webforms, fdf

> I am trying to...
>
> > 1. Open a database connection
> > 2. Put html form data into an Access 2007 database
> > 3. Pass that same form data into a already created PDF form using the FDF Toolkit
> > 4. Save that PDF form onto a network drive
> > 5. Display a message to the user, or preferably display the PDF that was just created.

I am passing the form data to the database just fine, I am having trouble with the....

objFDf.FDFSaveToFile ":\Project_Setup_Records\Test\" & "<%=rs1("PID")" & ".fdf"

It does not seem to like a variable in the path, although I could be barking up the wrong tree. I get the following message when I run the page....

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0401' 
Expected end of statement 
/forms/RequestConfirmation.asp, line 141 
objFDf.FDFSaveToFile "<Drive>:\Project_Setup_Records\Test\" & "<%=rs1("PID")" & ".fdf"
-----------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Can anyone analyze this code and suggest a way that I could get this FDF to save (I do need to have a unique FDF name for each FDF)? Thanks!

My code is below.....

```
<%@ LANGUAGE = VBScript%>
<%
'Dimension variables
Dim objConn          'Holds the Database Connection Object
Dim rs1              'Holds the recordset for the new record to be added
Dim strSQL           'Holds the SQL query to query the database

'Create an ADO connection object
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  

'Set an active connection to the Connection object using DSN connection
objConn.Open "DSN=XDRIVE"  

'Create an ADO recordset object
Set rs1 = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

'Initialise the strSQL variable with an SQL statement to query the database
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Data_Info;"

'Set the cursor type we are using so we can navigate through the recordset
rs1.CursorType = 2

'Set the lock type so that the record is locked by ADO when it is updated
rs1.LockType = 3

'Open the recordset with the SQL query 
rs1.Open strSQL, objConn

'Tell the recordset we are adding a new record to it
rs1.AddNew

'Add a new record to the recordset
rs1.Fields("PID") = Request.Form("PID")
rs1.Fields("EA") = Request.Form("EA")
rs1.Fields("Rte_Desc") = Request.Form("Rte_Desc")
rs1.Fields("PM_FN") = Request.Form("PM_FN")
rs1.Fields("PM_LN") = Request.Form("PM_LN")
rs1.Fields("PM_S_Num") = Request.Form("PM_S_Num")
rs1.Fields("PM_Phone") = Request.Form("PM_Phone")
rs1.Fields("PE_FN") = Request.Form("PE_FN")
rs1.Fields("PE_LN") = Request.Form("PE_LN")
rs1.Fields("PE_S_Num") = Request.Form("PE_S_Num")
rs1.Fields("PE_Phone") = Request.Form("PE_Phone")
rs1.Fields("FileMgr_FN") = Request.Form("FileMgr_FN")
rs1.Fields("FileMgr_LN") = Request.Form("FileMgr_LN")
rs1.Fields("FileMgr_S_Num") = Request.Form("FileMgr_S_Num")
rs1.Fields("FileMgr_Phone") = Request.Form("FileMgr_Phone")
rs1.Fields("Des_Ste_FN") = Request.Form("Des_Ste_FN")
rs1.Fields("Des_Ste_LN") = Request.Form("Des_Ste_LN")
rs1.Fields("Des_Ste_S_Num") = Request.Form("Des_Ste_S_Num")
rs1.Fields("Des_Ste_Phone") = Request.Form("Des_Ste_Phone")
rs1.Fields("Ass_Ste_FN") = Request.Form("Ass_Ste_FN")
rs1.Fields("Ass_Ste_LN") = Request.Form("Ass_Ste_LN")
rs1.Fields("Ass_Ste_S_Num") = Request.Form("Ass_Ste_S_Num")
rs1.Fields("Ass_Ste_Phone") = Request.Form("Ass_Ste_Phone")

'Write the updated recordset to the database
rs1.Update

'***   Create the FDF object.    
Set FdfAcX = Server.CreateObject("FdfApp.FdfApp")
Dim objFdf 
Set objFdf = FdfAcX.FDFCreate


'***   Set the location of the PDF file you create.
objFdf.FDFSetFile "http://xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/Design/design/forms/Project  Folder Information_Form.pdf"



'***   Set the variables with data from the various Request 
'***   data name/ value pairs posted from the HTML form. I'm using
'***   rather verbose code here, hopefully to benefit beginners 

PID = Request.form("PID")
EA = Request.form("EA")
Rte_Desc = Request.form("Rte_Desc")
PM_FN = Request.form("PM_FN")
PM_LN = Request.form("PM_LN")
PM_S_Num = Request.form("PM_S_Num")
PM_Phone = Request.form("PM_Phone")
PE_FN = Request.form("PE_FN")
PE_LN = Request.form("PE_LN")
PE_S_Num = Request.form("PE_S_Num")
PE_Phone = Request.form("PE_Phone")
FileMgr_FN = Request.form("FileMgr_FN")
FileMgr_LN = Request.form("FileMgr_LN")
FileMgr_S_Num = Request.form("FileMgr_S_Num")
FileMgr_Phone = Request.form("FileMgr_Phone")
Des_Ste_FN = Request.form("Des_Ste_FN")
Des_Ste_LN = Request.form("Des_Ste_LN")
Des_Ste_S_Num = Request.form("Des_Ste_S_Num")
Des_Ste_Phone = Request.form("Des_Ste_Phone")
Ass_Ste_FN = Request.form("Ass_Ste_FN")
Ass_Ste_LN = Request.form("Ass_Ste_LN")
Ass_Ste_S_Num = Request.form("Ass_Ste_S_Num")
Ass_Ste_Phone = Request.form("Ass_Ste_Phone")

'
'   Stuff the variables
'
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PID", PID, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "EA", EA, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Rte_Desc", Rte_Desc, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PM_FN", PM_FN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PM_LN", PM_LN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PM_S_Num", PM_S_Num, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PM_Phone", PM_Phone, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PE_FN", PE_FN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PE_LN", PE_LN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PE_S_Num", PE_S_Num, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "PE_Phone", PE_Phone, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "FileMgr_FN", FileMgr_FN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "FileMgr_LN", FileMgr_LN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "FileMgr_S_Num", FileMgr_S_Num, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "FileMgr_Phone", FileMgr_Phone, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Des_Ste_FN", Des_Ste_FN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Des_Ste_LN", Des_Ste_LN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Des_Ste_S_Num", Des_Ste_S_Num, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Des_Ste_Phone", Des_Ste_Phone, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Ass_Ste_FN", Ass_Ste_FN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Ass_Ste_LN", Ass_Ste_LN, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Ass_Ste_S_Num", Ass_Ste_S_Num, false
objFdf.fdfsetvalue "Ass_Ste_Phone", Ass_Ste_Phone, false

objFDF.fdfSetFile "<Drive>:\Project_Setup_Records\Project Folder Information_Form.pdf"
Response.ContentType = "text/html"
'
'   Save it to a file.  If you were going to save the actual file past the point of printing
'   You would want to create a naming convention (perhaps using social in the name)
'   Have to use the physical path so you may need to incorporate Server.mapPath in 
'   on this portion.
'

'***   Use the FDFSetStatus method to display an alert status box.
objFdf.FDFSetStatus "Your PDf File has been created and sent for review. You will be   notified when your folder has been created."

objFDf.FDFSaveToFile "<Drive>:\Project_Setup_Records\Test\" & "<%=rs1("PID")" & ".fdf"

' Now put a link to the file on your page. 
Response.Write "<a href=<%path%>X-Drive Request Form</a>"

'***   Write the data back to the buffer stream.
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.fdf"
Response.BinaryWrite objFdf.FDFSaveToBuf

'***   Close the object and clean-up.
objFdf.FDFClose
Set objFdf = Nothing
Set FdfAcX = Nothing

Response.end
'Redirect to the confirmation.asp page
'Response.Redirect "CreatePDF.asp"

'Reset server objects
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing
%>
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't have experience with ASP, but you probably should change this:

```
"P:\Project_Setup_Records\Test\" & "<%=rs1("PID")" & ".fdf"
```

into this:

```
"P:\Project_Setup_Records\Test\" & rs1("PID") & ".fdf"
```

if you want to produce a path with the PID as the file name.